# How to preserve local changes to a file on all branches, and after pulls, but never commit changes

Tags: git

I have certain config files (in RoR stuff like: .env, config/database.yml, .ruby-version), and I want to customize them on my local environment.

I know how to ignore the file so they are not tracked locally, but how can I stop the file being synced with the origin after a "pull", or "merge"?

Comment: If a file is not tracked by git it will not do any modification to it. 
What probably happens to you is that the file was already checked-in before you added to gitignore. If this is the case look this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1330097/19046

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to version only *template* of those config files, instead of the actual config files with their valued.
You could consider a [content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571580/6309) (using [`.gitattributes` declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/6309)) in order to generate the actual files.

The idea is to manage those config files in version, but with *template* placeholders in place of the actual (sensitive) values.
The generated files remains ignored (by the `.gitignore`)

- the smudge part could replace the template content with the actual value (on checkout)
- the clean part could restore the template (on commit)

[image: smudge]

<sup>(image from "[Customizing Git - Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion)", from "[Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/)")</sup>

The main idea is: if values are depending on the environment, the smudge script would replace the placeholder values with actual values depending on the environment, values fetched possible from *outside* the repo (this is especially true for production values).