# How to ignore changes in one of my local directory which is already checked-in?

Tags: git, github

I have a `GIT` repository where there is a `dist` folder which is required for some build/deploy job. On my local there is a chance of content change in that `dist` folder due to grunt build or something. But I don't want to commit those changes, so I want all the changes to be **ignored/untracked** in that directory (`dist`).

I have found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329291/ignoring-an-already-checked-in-directorys-contents) and tried `git rm -r --cached <your directory>`. But when I do `git status` after the above command it shows all the files have been deleted and `dist` folder has been untracked. So, if I commit this, then all the files will be deleted from central GIT repo also and I don't want that. I want GITHUB's dist folder to be untouched. Is there anything by which I can achieve this?

**Upadte 1:**
I have tried including in the `.git/info/exclude` file but still it did not work.

[image: exclude file]

I have changed a file inside `dist` but still it's showing in `git status`

[image: file inside dist folder]

Answer (score 2):

You can add `dist/` line to your local `.git/info/exclude`.

From [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

> Patterns which are specific to a particular repository but which do
>   not need to be shared with other related repositories (e.g., auxiliary
>   files that live inside the repository but are specific to one user’s
>   workflow) should go into the $GIT_DIR/info/exclude file.

---

For already existed files try:

`git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>`

and then when you want to track changes again:

`git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>`

Comment: Please see my update in the question. It did not work or am I missing something!

Comment: @DebajitMajumder seems that exclude method works only for new files, I have updated the response.

Comment: Yes this works but for **single file**. I have many sub-folders inside `dist` and all together there would be around 100 files inside `dist`. So, it's not really feasible to do it for each and every file. If you could suggest anything for the whole directory/folder?

Comment: In bash you can use something like this: `git ls-files <directory/folder> | xargs -n 100 git update-index --assume-unchanged`

Comment: Thanks man. Waiting for a better approach if there is any. This seems to be tweak but yes this would be my last option.

Comment: Another query: is there any command by which I can check the list of assume-unchanged file when I will execute `git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>`? because over the time if I do this for multiple files, it will be hard to remember, so it would be better if we have a command just like `git stash list`.

Comment: @DebajitMajumder `git ls-files -v | grep ^[a-z]`