# files from folder excluded in .gitignore appears in commits

Tags: git, gitignore

my `.gitignore` file contain `/var/` folder:

```
/.idea
/media/
/var/
/errors/
```

but files from `var/cache/` and `/.idea` appears regularly on new commits.

Yes, I did `git init` for entire project at the beginning, but also did `git rm -r --cached var/` as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/1330097/6827096 but new files still appears.
[image]

Comment: Add your `.gitignore` file content to the question as well. And also try adding `var/` instead of `/var`

Comment: try removing the 2nd line of your `.gitignore` it looks like you are telling git to ignore the .gitignore file

Comment: slashes at the beginnings did a job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be, it depends where the gitignore file is. If itś in the same directory as the folders do something like this:

```
.gitignore
.idea
/media
/var
/errors
```

or:

```
 .gitignore
 .idea
 media
 var
 errors
```

I would post this as a comment but I dont have enough rep for that  yet.

Comment: I must remove approval as it still adding new files from these directories.

Comment: Okey, can you also remove the .gitignore line? Because you must commit the gitignore aswell. And try running git rm r --cached <folder> for all those folders.

Comment: thanks you still there. I did it much earlier and still get these files. I will document detailed steps I do and put in main post later cause its looks like I'm doing it wrong way. Anyway main post contain updated version of my .gitignore.

Comment: I don't know if you solved it yet,  but one other problem could be that you didn't upload the gitignore file. (`git add .`) than commit it. (`git commit -m "added untracked fles"`) Please let me know if you got any further or add additional information.

Comment: my .gitignore looks like in my main post (and its edited based on your answer). I approved your answer as it just at some point stop adding new files from ignored directories. Im not sure why. I just did `git rm -r --cached ` couple of times and make sure git status is clean. (maybe before i didnt commit right after this command, i dont remember)